# Is it possible to use WindowsFormsHost in a MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, winforms-interop

I have a view model in which I create my windows forms in this way:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
```

My XAML is:

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <wfCharts:Chart x:Name="MyWinformChart" >
                    <wfCharts:Chart.Series>
                        <wfCharts:Series Name="SerieGraficoExterior" />
                    </wfCharts:Chart.Series>
                    <wfCharts:Chart.ChartAreas>
                        <wfCharts:ChartArea/>
                    </wfCharts:Chart.ChartAreas>
                </wfCharts:Chart>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
```

But I don't know if it's possible to bind to my view, because the `WindowsFormsHost` control has not a Content property like ContentControl, so I don't know if it's possible to use the `WindowsFormsHost` in a MVVM pattern. I did some tries with WPF, which worked in code behind, but I would like to use MVVM pattern if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed windows forms controls into a WPF application, but you cannot do bindings from a forms controls. A forms control does not have a datacontext property or dependency properties, which is the backbone of bindings.

That being said, you can still use the forms host in an MVVM application for everything except the forms controls, where you manually need to do the plumbing. So unless the main part of your application is based on windows forms, you can still get the benefits from MVVM.

Comment: So to create the chart (windows forms) I need to put the code in the code-behind?

Comment: No when you put it in XAML, the control is also being created. You can access the forms control from code-behind from its variable name (MyWinformChart)